# Location specific inventory retention in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I own a realm that has the "Keep Inventory" rule enabled. (so when one dies, their inventory is not dropped) I'm building a puzzle dungeon that other players can run through but I'd like there to be some risk. Is it possible to define an area where the "Keep Inventory" rule is false?

I'm sure I could copy the inventory of a player upon death, drop the items as entities and clear it but I'm wondering if there was a more direct way to accomplish this.

(Command Blocks are enabled)

Comment: No, it applies for everyone.

Comment: Would it suffice for the items to be simply gone or do you need them to drop on the floor?

Comment: I'd like them to drop on the floor so that it mimics standard behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Command Blocks would work if you put one with the **/gamerule keepInventory False** command into the entrance of the region of no keepInventory, hidden under a block that would activate it (such as a pressure plate). Be sure to reset this at the beginning and after this location with **/gamerule keepInventory true**.